# Simple equality proofs on lists in idris (prooving xs ++ [x] = ys ++ [y] -> x = y -> xs = ys)

Tags: idris, dependent-type, theorem-proving

I am learning idris and am very interested in proving properties about lists.

If you have a look at the [standard library](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/7af67ac426cfd0b5692c0ee5f12000d329d89d5b/libs/prelude/Prelude/List.idr#L876), theres a proof  that "Two lists are equal, if their heads are equal and their tails are equal."

```
consCong2 : {x : a} -> {xs : List a} -> {y : b} -> {ys : List b} ->
x = y -> xs = ys -> x :: xs = y :: ys
consCong2 Refl Refl = Refl
```

We can also prove the other direction

```
consCong2' : {x : a} -> {xs : List a} -> {y : b} -> {ys : List b} ->
x::xs = y::ys -> x = y -> xs = ys
consCong2' Refl Refl = Refl
```

Or even more explicitly, we can drop the heads on both side of the equations to get to the proof.

```
consCong2' : {x : a} -> {xs : List a} -> {y : b} -> {ys : List b} ->
x::xs = y::ys -> x = y -> xs = ys
consCong2' prf_cons Refl = (cong {f = drop 1} prf_cons)
```

It would be interesting to see if these properties can be proven also for the last item in the rest and everything before that.
Proving "Two lists are equal, if the first part and the very last item are equal" turned out to be very easy

```
consCong2' : {x : a} -> {xs : List a} -> {y : b} -> {ys : List b} ->
x = y -> xs = ys -> xs ++ [x] = ys ++ [y]
consCong2' Refl Refl = Refl
```

But the other direction fails the typecheck:

```
consCong2' : {x : a} -> {xs : List a} -> {y : b} -> {ys : List b} ->
xs ++ [x] = ys ++ [y] -> x = y -> xs = ys
consCong2' Refl Refl = Refl
```

Because

```
Type mismatch between
                         ys ++ [x]
                 and
                         xs ++ [x]
```

Obviously, because if `xs ++ [x] = ys ++ [y]` comes first in the deduction, idris can't possible unify both sides.

So all we need to do is tell idris to apply `init` on both sides of the equation,
like we did before with `drop 1`. 
That fails because init requires a proof that the list is non-empty, which somehow cannot be implicitly inferred here.
So for that i wrote a helper function, that explicitly defines `(a ++ [x]) = a`.

```
dropOneRight :  (xs : List a) -> List a
dropOneRight xs with (snocList xs)
  dropOneRight [] | Empty = []
  dropOneRight (a ++ [x]) | Snoc rec = a

consCong2' : {x : a} -> {xs : List a} -> {y : b} -> {ys : List b} ->
xs ++ [x] = ys ++ [y] -> x = y -> xs = ys
consCong2' prf_cons Refl = cong {f = dropOneRight} prf_cons
```

But this yields

```
Type mismatch between
                 dropOneRight (ys ++ [x])
         and
                 ys
```

I spend some time on other approaches, case-splitting using `snocList` but can not get notable progress. I don't understand how i can show idris that `dropOneRight (ys ++ [x]) = ys`. How can i prove `xs ++ [x] = ys ++ [y] -> x = y -> xs = ys`?

Comment: When you write "we can also prove the other direction", your result type should then really be a pair of a proof that `x = y` and `xs = ys`.

Comment: Yes! You're right, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the `snocList` approach will be tricky; at least with the simple proof strategy to follow the definition. To prove `ys = dropOneRight (ys ++ [x])` unifying `snocList (ys ++ [x])` with the arguments will cause trouble, roughly:

```
prf' : (ys : List a) -> (x : a) -> ys = dropOneRight (ys ++ [x])
prf' ys x with (snocList (ys ++ [x]))
    ...
    prf' ?? x | Snoc rec = ?hole
```

If you allow `dropOneRight` to be simpler, it's rather straight-forward:

```
dropOneRight : (xs : List a) -> List a
dropOneRight [] = []
dropOneRight [x] = []
dropOneRight (x :: y :: xs) = x :: dropOneRight (y :: xs)

dropPrf : (ys : List a) -> (x : a) -> ys = dropOneRight (ys ++ [x])
dropPrf [] z = Refl
dropPrf [x] z = Refl
dropPrf (x :: y :: xs) z = cong $ dropPrf (y::xs) z

consCong2' : {x : a} -> {xs : List a} -> {y : b} -> {ys : List b} ->
             xs ++ [x] = ys ++ [y] -> x = y -> xs = ys
consCong2' {xs} {ys} {x} prf_cons Refl = 
  rewrite dropPrf ys x in rewrite dropPrf xs x in
  cong prf_cons
```